# Implementing nsIProtocolHandler with Delphi

Tags: delphi, firefox, delphi-7, gecko

I'm trying to build an nsIProtocolHandler implementation in Delphi. (I've done an IInternetProtocol before with success, and want to have in FireFox what I've got in Internet Explorer.)
Thanks to [the d-gecko](http://sourceforge.net/projects/d-gecko) project, that somehow links the TInterfacedObject magic to the nsISupports magic, I'm able to make a DLL that provides an nsIModule when asked, which provides an nsIFactory when asked, which provides one of my nsIProtocolHandler's when asked, which provides one of my nsIChannel/nsIHttpChannel's when asked.

When debugging using firefox.exe as host process, I can see my library gets loaded, NewURI gets called three times, NewChannel gets called, and I pass an object that implements nsIChannel and [nsIHttpChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIHttpChannel).

This is where I'm troubled. I'm not supposed to call OnStartRequest and OnDataAvailable on the nsIStreamListener I get, until I return control from AsyncOpen, but I don't seem to get control back in the thread that AsyncOpen was called in.

I've tried debugging with a self-made wrapper around a default http handler (gotten with `CreateInstanceByContractID('@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http',`...). I also wrapped the listener passed. Oddly enough, I see OnStartRequest and OnDataAvailable get called *after* my channel wrapper dies, in the same thread. But who's calling? If it's the http-channel I was trying to wrap, how does it survive (in the same thread) and how does it get control to call the listener? I'm baffled. And stuck.

I've tried to contact the main developer of the d-gecko project, but got no response.

(Also, did someone ever notice my blurb at the bottom of the [talk page on MDC on nsIProtocolHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk:En/NsIProtocolHandler)?)

(Oh one more thing, yes I know "life would be simpler" if I would just inherit from nsBaseChannel in C++. But the point is to add a FireFox protocol-handler to an existing Delphi project core.)

**Update:** I've done some more reading, It's mentioned [here](http://www.oxymoronical.com/experiments/apidocs/platform/1.9.1b3pre/interface/nsIStreamListener/usage) as well: "The stream listener's methods are
 called on the thread that calls asyncOpen [...]" but how that is possible without being called from the 'hosting application' first, isn't clear to me. Is that an XPCOM trick? I guess I'll have to read (a lot) more firefox source before I get it.

Comment: is anyone is interested, I released a version yesterday that's ready for FireFox 7.0: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAHYFsWU6e2tKz%2BrJzac5VTtSH%3DZWLq3aRTqzvAFPDxSfTOGUEA%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=xxm-releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about Mozilla coding, but here it goes.

According to [nsIChannel::asyncOpen()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIChannel#asyncOpen%28%29),

> Asynchronously open this channel. Data
>   is fed to the specified stream
>   listener as it becomes available. The
>   stream listener's methods are called
>   on the thread that calls asyncOpen and
>   are not called until after asyncOpen
>   returns. If asyncOpen returns
>   successfully, the channel promises to
>   call at least onStartRequest and
>   onStopRequest.

So as the protocol hander, you implement a channel object on your own or redirect it to a channel object, the consumer of the channel calls your channel up using `asyncOpen()`. Since it is an async call, the idea is to return the control back to the consumer immediately, and it is suppose to call the callbacks as it loads in the data.

I am not sure if I understand what you mean by "but I don't seem to get control back in the thread that AsyncOpen was called in."  The thread is created by the consumer of your protocol, and it opens the channel.

Also from [nsIChannel::asyncOpen()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIChannel#asyncOpen%28%29):

> If asyncOpen returns successfully, the
>   channel is responsible for keeping
>   itself alive until it has called
>   onStopRequest on aListener or called
>   onChannelRedirect.

Since asyncOpen returns the control right back, the channel itself needs to keep itself alive somewhere.

If you are looking for example code, I found codase to be very useful. See [nsIProtocolHandler](http://codase.com/search/call?name=nsIProtocolHandler) and 
[nsIChannel](http://codase.com/search/call?name=nsIChannel). Using that I came across [view-source protocol](http://web.mit.edu/Source/third/mozilla/netwerk/protocol/viewsource/src/) (this implementation may be older, but doesn't matter).

[`nsViewSourceHandler`](http://web.mit.edu/Source/third/mozilla/netwerk/protocol/viewsource/src/nsViewSourceHandler.cpp) implements custom channel.

```
nsViewSourceHandler::NewChannel(nsIURI* uri, nsIChannel* *result)
{
    nsresult rv;

    nsViewSourceChannel* channel;
    rv = nsViewSourceChannel::Create(nsnull, NS_GET_IID(nsIChannel), (void**)&channel);
    if (NS_FAILED(rv)) return rv;

    rv = channel->Init(uri);
    if (NS_FAILED(rv)) {
        NS_RELEASE(channel);
        return rv;
    }

    *result = NS_STATIC_CAST(nsIViewSourceChannel*, channel);
    return NS_OK;
}
```

Here's the [`nsViewSourceChannel`](http://web.mit.edu/Source/third/mozilla/netwerk/protocol/viewsource/src/nsViewSourceChannel.cpp)'s AsyncOpen:

```
nsViewSourceChannel::AsyncOpen(nsIStreamListener *aListener, nsISupports *ctxt)
{
    NS_ENSURE_TRUE(mChannel, NS_ERROR_FAILURE);

    mListener = aListener;

    /*
     * We want to add ourselves to the loadgroup before opening
     * mChannel, since we want to make sure we're in the loadgroup
     * when mChannel finishes and fires OnStopRequest()
     */

    nsCOMPtr<nsILoadGroup> loadGroup;
    mChannel->GetLoadGroup(getter_AddRefs(loadGroup));
    if (loadGroup)
        loadGroup->AddRequest(NS_STATIC_CAST(nsIViewSourceChannel*,
                                             this), nsnull);

    nsresult rv = mChannel->AsyncOpen(this, ctxt);

    if (NS_FAILED(rv) && loadGroup)
        loadGroup->RemoveRequest(NS_STATIC_CAST(nsIViewSourceChannel*,
                                                this),
                                 nsnull, rv);

    if (NS_SUCCEEDED(rv)) {
        mOpened = PR_TRUE;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

Anyway, this is a long and winding way of asking, how are you creating your channel?

Comment: Congratulations, you've earned 300 points. I was silently hoping that noone would answer, and I would get the points back when then bounty expires, but hey, thanks for the answer. It's clarifying. And I learned about codase.com (I was using www.google.com/codesearch and mxr.mozilla.org/firefox before).
In the mean time since posting this question, I learned about NS_DispatchToMainThread which answers my question. I was also doing something wrong in the nsACString conversions, so I'm no longer stuck... If you're interested: http://xxm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xxm/trunk/Delphi/gecko/

Comment: I've been working more on this, so for whomever is interested: now I catch the 'current thread' when my AsyncOpen is called, and dispatch events to that thread to call the listener. Since this is the only answer and was some help, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can post your own answer, and I'd gladly give up the accepted state.