# nsIProtocolHandler: trouble loading image for html page

Tags: delphi, firefox, gecko

I'm building an nsIProtocolHandler implementation in Delphi. ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864443/implementing-nsiprotocolhandler-with-delphi))
And it's working already. Data the module builds gets streamed over an nsIInputStream. I've got all the nsIRequest, nsIChannel and nsIHttpChannel methods and properties working.

I've started testing and I run into something strange. I have a page "a.html" with this simple HTML:

`<img src="a.png">`

Both "xxm://test/a.html" and "xxm://test/a.png" work in Firefox, and give above HTML or the PNG image data.
The problem is with displaying the HTML page, the image doesn't get loaded. When I debug, I see:

- NewChannel gets called for a.png, (when Firefox is processing an OnDataAvailable notice on a.html),
- NotificationCallbacks is set (I only need to keep a reference, right?)
- RequestHeader "`Accept`" is set to "`image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5`"
- but then, the channel object is released (most probably due to a zero reference count)

Looking at other requests, I would expect some other properties to get set (such as LoadFlags or OriginalURI) and [AsyncOpen](http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/netwerk/base/public/nsIChannel.idl#205) to get called, from where I can start getting the request responded to.

Does anybody recognise this? Am I doing something wrong? Perhaps with LoadFlags or the LoadGroup? I'm not sure when to call AddRequest and RemoveRequest on the LoadGroup, and peeping from [nsHttpChannel](http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/netwerk/protocol/http/src/nsHttpHandler.cpp) and [nsBaseChannel](http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/netwerk/base/src/nsBaseChannel.cpp) I'm not sure it's better to call RemoveRequest early or late (before or after OnStartRequest or OnStopRequest)?

**Update:** Checked on the freshly new Firefox 3.5, still the same

**Update:** To try to further isolate the issue, I try "file://test/a1.html" with `<img src="xxm://test/a.png" />` and still only get above sequence of events happening. *If* I'm supposed to add this secundary request to a load-group to get AsyncOpen called on it, I have no idea where to get a reference to it.

There's more: I find only [one instance](http://tinyurl.com/le7m77) of the "Accept" string that get's added to the request headers, it queries for nsIHttpChannelInternal right after creating a new channel, but I don't even get this QueryInterface call through... (I posted it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501952))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it (myself), take a close look at [this page](http://www.oxymoronical.com/experiments/apidocs/compare/interface/nsIHttpChannelInternal/1.9.0.0/1.9.1b2). Why it doesn't highlight that the UUID has been changed over versions, isn't clear to me, but it would explain why things fail when (or just prior to) calling QueryInterface on nsIHttpChannelInternal.

With the new(er) UUID, I'm getting better results. As I mentioned in an update to the question, I've posted this on bugzilla.mozilla.org, I'm curious if and which response I will get there.

Answer (score 0):

Me again.

I am going to quote the same stuff from [`nsIChannel::asyncOpen()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/NsIChannel#asyncOpen.28.29):

> If `asyncOpen` returns successfully, the
>   channel is responsible for keeping
>   itself alive until it has called
>   `onStopRequest` on `aListener` or called
>   `onChannelRedirect`.

If you go back to [nsViewSourceChannel.cpp](http://web.mit.edu/Source/third/mozilla/netwerk/protocol/viewsource/src/nsViewSourceChannel.cpp), there's one place where `loadGroup->AddRequest` is called and two places where `loadGroup->RemoveRequest` is being called.

```
nsViewSourceChannel::AsyncOpen(nsIStreamListener *aListener, nsISupports *ctxt)
{
    NS_ENSURE_TRUE(mChannel, NS_ERROR_FAILURE);

    mListener = aListener;

    /*
     * We want to add ourselves to the loadgroup before opening
     * mChannel, since we want to make sure we're in the loadgroup
     * when mChannel finishes and fires OnStopRequest()
     */

    nsCOMPtr<nsILoadGroup> loadGroup;
    mChannel->GetLoadGroup(getter_AddRefs(loadGroup));
    if (loadGroup)
        loadGroup->AddRequest(NS_STATIC_CAST(nsIViewSourceChannel*,
                                             this), nsnull);

    nsresult rv = mChannel->AsyncOpen(this, ctxt);

    if (NS_FAILED(rv) && loadGroup)
        loadGroup->RemoveRequest(NS_STATIC_CAST(nsIViewSourceChannel*,
                                                this),
                                 nsnull, rv);

    if (NS_SUCCEEDED(rv)) {
        mOpened = PR_TRUE;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

and

```
nsViewSourceChannel::OnStopRequest(nsIRequest *aRequest, nsISupports* aContext,
                               nsresult aStatus)
{
    NS_ENSURE_TRUE(mListener, NS_ERROR_FAILURE);
    if (mChannel)
    {
        nsCOMPtr<nsILoadGroup> loadGroup;
        mChannel->GetLoadGroup(getter_AddRefs(loadGroup));
        if (loadGroup)
        {
            loadGroup->RemoveRequest(NS_STATIC_CAST(nsIViewSourceChannel*,
                                                    this),
                                     nsnull, aStatus);
        }
    }
    return mListener->OnStopRequest(NS_STATIC_CAST(nsIViewSourceChannel*,
                                                   this),
                                    aContext, aStatus);
}
```

**Edit**:

As I have no clue about how Mozilla works, so I have to guess from reading some code. From the channel's point of view, once the original file is loaded, its job is done. If you want to load the secondary items linked in file like an image, you have to implement that in the listener. See [TestPageLoad.cpp](http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/netwerk/test/TestPageLoad.cpp). It implements a crude parser and it retrieves child items upon `OnDataAvailable`:

```
NS_IMETHODIMP
MyListener::OnDataAvailable(nsIRequest *req, nsISupports *ctxt,
                            nsIInputStream *stream,
                            PRUint32 offset, PRUint32 count)
{
    //printf(">>> OnDataAvailable [count=%u]\n", count);
    nsresult rv = NS_ERROR_FAILURE;
    PRUint32 bytesRead=0;
    char buf[1024];

    if(ctxt == nsnull) {
      bytesRead=0;
      rv = stream->ReadSegments(streamParse, &offset, count, &bytesRead);
    } else {
      while (count) {
        PRUint32 amount = PR_MIN(count, sizeof(buf));
        rv = stream->Read(buf, amount, &bytesRead);  
        count -= bytesRead;
      }
    }

    if (NS_FAILED(rv)) {
      printf(">>> stream->Read failed with rv=%x\n", rv);
      return rv;
    }

    return NS_OK;
}
```

The important thing is that it calls `streamParse()`, which looks at `src` attribute of `img` and `script` element, and calls `auxLoad()`, which creates new channel with new listener and calls `AsyncOpen()`.

```
uriList->AppendElement(uri);
rv = NS_NewChannel(getter_AddRefs(chan), uri, nsnull, nsnull, callbacks);
RETURN_IF_FAILED(rv, "NS_NewChannel");

gKeepRunning++;
rv = chan->AsyncOpen(listener, myBool);
RETURN_IF_FAILED(rv, "AsyncOpen");
```

Since it's passing in another instance of `MyListener` object in there, that can also load more child items ad infinitum like a Russian doll situation.

Comment: This is very confusing. I have my AddRequest/RemoveRequest calls in very comparable places, but neither SetLoadGroup or AsyncOpen get called on the png's channel. ViewSourceChannel uses "mChannel", which gets set on its nsIStreamListener.OnStartRequest call, but if I add nsIStreamListener to my channel, its methods don't get called...